# Matplotlib plt.text(), Chinese Character, the text on canvas will disappear when repeat drawing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working on a real-time character recognition system.

When using `matplotlib.pyplot.text()` to show the result, I find the Chinese Characters are incorrectly displayed when the canvas refreshes. To be more specific, the text image will disappear when the second(or more) drawing round comes, with the same character.

Demo problem code are as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['SimHei']
plt.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = True

canvas_size = 8
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(canvas_size, canvas_size))

while True:
    # plt.text(0.25, 0.4, 'A', fontsize=100)        # test1: Correct when refreash
    plt.text(0.25, 0.4, '中', fontsize=100)         # test2: Incorrect when refreash
    # plt.text(0.25, 0.4, u'\u54c8', fontsize=100)  # test3: Incorrect when refreash
    plt.title("Result")
    plt.pause(3)
```

Why this happens, and how to make `test2 / test3` displays correctly？

Any comments or suggests will be appreciated!

Comment: It works fine with matplotlib 3.2.1 and Python 3.6.8.